# DNS Cache affecting HTTP requests

Tags: windows, dns, cache

An odd error occured which I am trying to understand the cause.  I updated a website and on some computers, a cached version of a particular .css file was being served.  Other changes to the site were correctly showing.  The error showed up in all browsers (cleared cache and all) and even by using wget.  I disabled caching on the webserver and still the issue occured.  If I appeneded a random querystring to the url, I would then get the correct file.

Example:

```
http://server/dir/file.css <- wrong file
http://server/dir/files.css?v=1 <- right file
```

I eventually was able to fix it by running the following command on the workstations (not the server)

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

This worked on all workstations which could not retrieve the correct file.  I am at a loss as to how the DNS Cache could affect http requests and was wondering if anyone has an explanation for it?

Comment: Did you happen to try reloading the page with CTRL-F5 to force a server refresh of the page?  I use long expiration times on CSS (like a year) and actually increment the name of the file if I edit it... example main-v2_1.css

Comment: Is there a proxy in front of the webserver? As Tyson mentioned, CTRL+F5 to refresh is worth trying, to force a reload of the page.

Comment: I did hard-refreshes in all the browsers (this was happening in IE, Firefox and Chrome) and it wasn't refreshing the file.